# Dereference of undefined pointer value?

Tags: c, pointers, undefined, dereference

I'm trying to malloc a 3d array and then initialise it, as follows, the problem is, I get a warning saying I'm trying to 'dereference an undefined pointer value' in the following line:                       `Parque->matriz[i][j][p]='@';`

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

My code is as follows:

```
parque *Parque;
Parque = (parque *) malloc(sizeof(parque));


Parque->matriz = (char***)malloc(x * sizeof(char **));


    for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        Parque->matriz[i] = (char**)malloc(y * sizeof(char*));

        for (j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {
            Parque->matriz[i][j] = (char*)malloc(z*sizeof(char));

        }
    }

    for (p=0; p<z; p++)
    {
        for (j=y-1;j>=0; j--)
        {
            for (i=0; i<x; i++)
            {
                Parque->matriz[i][j][p]='@';

            }
        }
    }
```

and this is the definition of struct parque:

```
struct  _parque{
    int dimx;
    int dimy;
    int pisos;
    int entradas;
    int acessos;
    int nodes;
    char ***matriz;
    int capacidade;
    int lugares_ocupados;
};

typedef struct _parque parque;
```

Comment: What's assigned to `Parque`?

Comment: I think Parque is some kind of struct but I would like to see the definition of that first.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I forgot to post its definition. @dasblinkenlight

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I forgot to post its definition. @arduic

Comment: Running this code with `i`,`j`,and `p` defined as `int` and `x`,`y`, and `z` defined as int with some default values runs fine with no complaints from Valgrind.  Can you come up with a stand-alone example that still exhibits this issue?  Also, what system / compiler are you using?

Comment: Consider posting code that we can easily compile, this version has missing variable declarations and no `main`. Anyway I wasn't able to reproduce the problem; can you show us exactly what you're doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems correct, though you have a funny way of iterating over the indices. Maybe your compiler got confused. Please try:

```
for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    Parque->matriz[i] = (char**)malloc(y * sizeof(char*));

    for (j = 0; j < y; j++)
    {
        Parque->matriz[i][j] = (char*)malloc(z*sizeof(char));

        for (p = 0; p < z; p++)
        {
            Parque->matriz[i][j][p]='@';

        }

    }
}
```

This would be semantically equivalent to you second set of nested loops.